# How do I reuse an HTML element on the same page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a div element called `main-middle-column-container` in my HTML and styled it with CSS. Basically, `main-middle-column-container` will create a twitter-like message box that will have a name, date/time, and the message.

I want to reuse `main-middle-column-container` and all the code inside of it with jQuery so that when new data comes in, it will use a fresh `main-middle-column-container` as a template to add in the new values (like how twitter would work). When new data comes in, `@username`, `date/time`, and `This is a random message. #random` will be replaced with the incoming data or leave the elements empty and have the new data fill it in.

I thought about using `$('.main-middle-column-container').clone().appendTo('.main-middle-column-wrapper');` but that will keep double cloning it (1 box -> 2 box -> 4 box -> 8 box...) instead of cloning it once. I also have an issue of getting rid of `main-middle-column-container` before I receive any data because I don't want an empty box on the website I am trying to create. I want `main-middle-column-container` to be created right when I get some kind of data/message.

**CSS and HTML (message box)**

```css
.main-middle-column-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 49%;
}

.main-middle-column-container{
  width: 100%;
}

.main-middle-column{
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial ,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  z-index: -2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

.main-middle-column:hover{
  background-color: hsl(200, 23%, 96%);
}

.tweet-pic-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.tweet-pic-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tweet-pic{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  left: -6px;
  width: auto;
}

.title-account-time{
  margin-left: 55px;
}

.msg-title{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.msg-acc-name{
  color: #657786;
}

.msg-acc-name:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.msg-date{
  color: #657786;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.tweet-msg{
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-middle-column-wrapper">
  <div class="main-middle-column-container">
    <div class="main-middle-column">
      <div class="tweet-pic-wrapper">
        <div class="tweet-pic-container">
          <img src="Picture of the Moon.jpeg" class="tweet-pic" alt="Picture of the moon.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title-account-time">
        <span class="msg-title">My Twitter</span>
        <span class="msg-acc-name">@username</span>
        <div class="msg-date">date/time</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tweet-msg">
        This is a random message. #random
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is you are setting a *class* for main-middle-column-wrapper, so whenever you do $('.main-middle-column-container').clone() it runs on every element that has that class, thus you are exponentially increasing the amount of elements doing this as you duplicate 1, then 2, then 4 elements with the same class. I would suggest creating a function to which you pass the parameters you care to put into that HTML, and generate the HTML with javascript/jquery and then insert it or return it.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have a solution for you, you can create a 'template' and retrieve that template with jquery.
If you put this in your main html file

```
<script id="hidden-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
    <div class="main-middle-column-wrapper">
  <div class="main-middle-column-container">
    <div class="main-middle-column">
      <div class="tweet-pic-wrapper">
        <div class="tweet-pic-container">
          <img src="Picture of the Moon.jpeg" class="tweet-pic" alt="Picture of the moon.">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title-account-time">
        <span class="msg-title">My Twitter</span>
        <span class="msg-acc-name">@username</span>
        <div class="msg-date">date/time</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tweet-msg">
        this is a story all about how my life got flipped turned upside down and id like to take a minute and just sit right there id like to tell you how i became a prince in a town called belair.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</script>
```

You can get the content with jquery like this

```
var template = $('#hidden-template').html();
```

Now you have your html 'template' in your javascipt, now your can create more than one of these elements.

```
$('#target').append(template);
```

Or you can use a better/simpler method with plain javascript

```
const card = ({ img_alt, img_src, title, username, date, msg }) => `
  <div class="main-middle-column-wrapper">
  <div class="main-middle-column-container">
    <div class="main-middle-column">
      <div class="tweet-pic-wrapper">
        <div class="tweet-pic-container">
          <img src="${img_src}" class="tweet-pic" alt="${img_alt}">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="title-account-time">
        <span class="msg-title">${title}</span>
        <span class="msg-acc-name">@${username}</span>
        <div class="msg-date">${date}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tweet-msg">${msg}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
`;
```

You can use this as a function to create your elements dynamically with all kinds of data.

Comment: Great idea with the card function. In case any are wondering like I was how to call such a function: 
<script>$(".main-middle-container-wrapper").html(card(<your parameters>));</script>

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that returns a Template Literal with the desired HTML markup structure.  Map your tweets and insert them into a target parent:

```js
const tweets = [
  {
    _id: 321,
    pic: "https://placehold.it/80x80/0bf",
    title: "My Twitter",
    name: "@username",
    date: "2020-01-18",
    msg: "this is a story"
  },
  {
    _id: 231,
    pic: "https://placehold.it/80x80/f0b",
    title: "My alter Twitter",
    name: "@user",
    date: "2020-01-19",
    msg: "Again, another story"
  }
];

const newTweet = tweet => `<div class="main-middle-column">
    <div class="tweet-pic-wrapper">
      <div class="tweet-pic-container">
        <img src="${tweet.pic}" class="tweet-pic" alt="${tweet.title}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="title-account-time">
      <span class="msg-title">${tweet.title}</span>
      <span class="msg-acc-name">${tweet.name}</span>
      <div class="msg-date">${tweet.date}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tweet-msg">${tweet.msg}</div>
  </div>`; 
  
const populateNewTweets = (tweets, parent) => {
  if (!tweets.length) return;
  $('<div>', {
    class: 'main-middle-column-container',
    appendTo: parent,
    append: tweets.map(newTweet)
  });
};

populateNewTweets(tweets, '.main-middle-column-wrapper');
```

```css
.main-middle-column-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 49%;
}

.main-middle-column-container{
  width: 100%;
}

.main-middle-column{
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial ,sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  z-index: -2;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 lightgray;
  position: relative;
}

.main-middle-column:hover{
  background-color: hsl(200, 23%, 96%);
}

.tweet-pic-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

.tweet-pic-container{
  position: relative;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tweet-pic{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  left: -6px;
  width: auto;
}

.title-account-time{
  margin-left: 55px;
}

.msg-title{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.msg-acc-name{
  color: #657786;
}

.msg-acc-name:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.msg-date{
  color: #657786;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.tweet-msg{
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-middle-column-wrapper"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this would be to use some kind of templating engine, for example [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/). If that however is out of the question, the solution to your problem would be something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     /* this should store the container templates clone in a variable */
     mainMiddleContainerTemplate = jQuery(".main-middle-column-container").get(0).clone();

     /* this should remove every main middle container from the view, in case
        you have multiple containers that are not templates, consider adding
        an additional class to your template container */
     jQuery(".main-middle-column-container").remove();
});

function addNewContainer(containerData) {
    var newContainer = mainMiddleContainerTemplate.clone();

    /** add and replace all the data needed on the newContainer **/
    newContainer.find('.message-title').html(containerData.title);
    newContainer.find('.msg-acc-name').html(containerData.accountName);
    ....

    jQuery(".main-middle-container-wrapper").append(newContainer);
}
```

But still, I would advice you, to use a templating engine for these kinds of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.main-middle-column-container').first().clone().appendTo('.main-middle-column-wrapper');
```

The key is to select only one element to be cloned. First is as good as any other.